# Rails - Get Return Value from Data Confirm

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unobtrusive-javascript, blockui

I have a delete button in my web application that uses the following code:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", gradebook_category_path(:id => c.id, :gradebook_id => @gradebook.id), method: :delete, class: 'delete', remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure? You will lose all grade information associated with this category!' } %>
```

Because of the "confirm" data attribute, when you click the delete button, a confirm popup shows that asks the user if he is really sure he wants to delete the category. If yes, the category is removed from the database, if not, the category stays.

Is there a way to execute some jQuery after the user clicks "OK" on the confirm dialog, and before the delete action in the controller is called?

Specifically, I want to use jQuery BlockUI to block the Category in the UI only when the user clicks "OK", and not when the user clicks "Cancel".

So currently I have this:

```
$('.title_bar_container .delete').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().block({message: '<h2><img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" /> Deleting category...</h2>'})
});
```

which will block the Category on the UI whether I click "OK" or click "Cancel". I just want the UI to block when "OK" is clicked.

I understand that it is possible to create a confirm dialog using "windows.confirm", however I really want to stick with using the Rails built in unobtrusive Javascript driver.

Any ideas? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I apologize, but this was a while ago. I don't remember what I did to solve this issue.